# How to center and indent a particular paragraph in LaTex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I just want to centre and indent a particular paragraph.
Everything else shall stay the same?

How can I do this in LaTex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `quotation` environment does this, though it does add a little extra vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quotation}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the extra vertical space, use `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\leftskip=1cm\rightskip=1cm
\lipsum[2]

\leftskip=0cm\rightskip=0cm
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your suggested answer. This indents the text ... but how can I also center it? (at the moment it's indented but not centered)

Comment: @steady_progress It is left/right centered between the margins.  What did you mean by "centered"?

Comment: it's ok ... it had to do with sth else